# Math expressions with knockout through jquery.tmpl values?

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-templates

Doing math expressions in jquery.tmpl for knockout viewmodels doesn't seem to work. Is there another way to do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/Z8F8r/

```
<p data-bind="text: number" /> <-- shows 10 as expected

<script id="numberTemplate" type="text/html">
    ${number} <-- Shows 10 as expected
    ${number/2} <-- Shows NaN
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't work. The link to jquery tmpl isn't text/javascript. I tried to use the microsoft CDN and knockout is upset at the version.

Comment: @awbergs Looks fine enough in FireFox. Attached a screenshot just in case.

Comment: Must be a chrome issue. I'll check it out in FF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `number` value is not the actual value. It's a function that, when called with 0 arguments, returns the expected value. When you evaluate the expression

```
${number / 2}
```

you're effectively doing the same thing as

```
(function(){}) / 2
```

which returns `NaN`

If you change the expression to look like this instead

```
${number() / 2}
```

You will get the expected value of `5`

You can see the actual contents of `number` if you `eval` the value.

```
${eval(number)}
```

returns this function

```
function d(){
    if(0<arguments.length)
    {
        if(!d.equalityComparer||!d.equalityComparer(c,arguments[0]))
            d.H(),
            c=arguments[0],
            d.G();
            return this
    }

    b.r.Wa(d);
    return c
}
```

Comment: You are my favorite person! Thanks!